# unable to install composer for laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i am trying to install composer on my xampp server, but i am getting following error.
[image]

Any leads would be helpful. thank you

Comment: Edit into \xampp\php\php.ini look like this extension=php_pdo.dll.

Comment: @SyedNoman No extension as such in my php.ini file.

Comment: have you downloaded php?

Comment: @YaShChaudhary.. no but i did download memcache module. may be due to its incompatibility with php version the above error is coming. i want to know how to find compatible memecache module compatible with my php version

Comment: replacing php_memcache.dll file with compatible to php version resolved the issue. thank you folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be many reasons behind this.

1.) Be sure Your xampp is working fine.

2.) You install composer without selecting php.exe file (Default it will be available in C:\xampp\php\php.exe).

If all working fine please look at this link. May be it will help you:
https://abuango.net/2014/08/16/how-to-install-composer-on-windows-with-xampp/

Comment: sorry but issue still persist. @Manish